# How to install beammech module or something similar capable of doing beam analysis?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am runnning a 64-bit windows system and I am using anaconda-jupyter_notebook, and python version 3.7.

I have been coding indeterminate beams manually for a while not however inputting all those formulas each time makes it a quite pedantic procedure.

I read up about a module called `sympy.physics.continuum_mechanics.beam` which appears to be capable of doing what want, however it does not seam available on python 3.7.

Similarly, I tried installing the `beammech.py` module, but this does not exist either in the anaconda installer library, this is probably because it is still being developed in python 3.6+.

In command line I tried the following:

```
conda install beammech 
conda install sympy.physics.continuum_mechanics.beam
```

At first I thought it was because I am not running cmd as an administrator, however this was not the problem.

I tried the `anaconda search -t conda beammech` and my search results where:

```
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
No packages found
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
Found 0 packages
```

I tried pypi.org and found femethods. However after installation I do not know where to import it from. This module is also restricted since it does not allow me to use distributed loads.

Please advise if you can.

Thank you M.